# State management in vue3 with vuex4 fails - Code shared in codesandbox

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

Dear friends of the modern lightweight web, I hope you can help a noobie regarding vue3 and Vuex 4.

I share timetable details (array of objects/dictionary) between multiple child components, which then can be displayed (e.g. Top 5 work) or edited (e.g. add new work details) in a way that these changes get reflected in all the other components. For this, I tried to use Vuex 4.

I am not able to access the state in a component. For debugging reasons, I even added a dummy entry during the creation of the state.

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-brahmagupta-5sn1t?file=/src/main.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your demo uses Vuex 3 (perhaps that was a mistake only in the demo). Be sure to install Vuex 4, which provides the [`createStore()`](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/api/#createstore) method:

```sh
npm i -S vuex@4
```

Also, the result of `createStore()` should be passed to [`app.use()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#use), which is an instance method of the app from `createApp()` (not the `App.vue` component):

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import App from './App.vue'

const store = createStore(/*...*/)

// App.use(store) ❌ don't do this

createApp(App)
  .use(store) ✅
  .mount('#app')
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-vuex-in-vue-3-m4hqp?file=/src/main.js:335-376)